# Using variable for UPDATE() the checker if the column is Updated or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Is it possible to use a variable in UPDATE() which check if a column is updated or not?

here is my sample code:

```
DECLARE @ColumnCount int
DECLARE @ColumnCounter int
DECLARE @ColumnName nvarchar(MAX)

SET @ColumnCounter = 0

SELECT @ColumnCount =  COUNT(c.COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c  WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'Province'
    WHILE @ColumnCount >= @ColumnCounter
    BEGIN
       SELECT @ColumnName = c.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c  WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'Province' AND c.ORDINAL_POSITION = @ColumnCounter
        IF (UPDATE(@ColumnName))
       SET @ColumnCounter = @ColumnCounter + 1
    END
```

Comment: Are you trying to tell if the @ColumnName variable has been updated by the select above it?

Comment: yes i am trying to check if the column is updated

Comment: Then all you have to do is set it to null before and then check to see if it's is not null.  I will write it for you in an answer below.

Comment: Check that, you need to declare another variable and set it to the current variable so you can check it the next time through the loop.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:
You may want to handle the first time through the loop because the name would not have changed the first time through.
You may want to handle when @ColumnName is null because that would mean your query did not return a row although your query below should always return a value.

```
DECLARE @ColumnCount INT 
DECLARE @ColumnCounter INT 
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @temp varchar(max)

SET @ColumnCounter = 0 

SELECT @ColumnCount = Count(c.column_name) 
FROM   information_schema.columns c 
WHERE  c.table_name = 'Province' 

WHILE @ColumnCount >= @ColumnCounter 
  BEGIN 
      SET @ColumnName = NULL 

      SELECT @ColumnName = c.column_name 
      FROM   information_schema.columns c 
      WHERE  c.table_name = 'Province' 
             AND c.ordinal_position = @ColumnCounter 

      IF ( @ColumnName != @temp ) 
        BEGIN 
        --do something 
        END
      SET @temp = @ColumnName
      SET @ColumnCounter = @ColumnCounter + 1 
  END
```

Comment: hmmm how can i check if the column is updated? my code is place in the trigger after update

Comment: Oh, the trigger part wasn't mentioned anywhere.  You can't do a check on variable name for a statement in a trigger.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

to check for column is actually updated in after update trigger
you can use `deleted` and `inserted` special tables [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) in which trigger code can find old and new versions of rows of updating table

remember that it is possible to find there more than 1 row in each table. for example you execute `update table1 set col1 = value1 where some_condition` in trigger number of rows affects by `some_condition`, will be presented in `inserted` and `deleted` tables

to find out in trigger in what rows some column is actual updating, you can join inserted and deleted tables on some primary key and compare values of this column

the `update()` function takes as parameter column name not a sting variable with name as value

for example using `update()` in triggers check [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1479581/Using-Update-in-Triggers.htm) `update(some_column)` is true when `some_column` present in update `set` statement, even value of column not changing.

it seems like you can not write universal trigger to count number of columns updated, if you need that count you need to manually write trigger for each table with somethig like this

```
declare @count int = 0
if update(col1) set @count = @count + 1
if update(col2) set @count = @count + 1
...
```

Comment: Another way to count the columns "updated" is to count the set bits in the result from [`Columns_Updated()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). The column names aren't needed.